# Почему "строительные леса" так называются?

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова, омонимы

Мы знаем, что строительные конструкции, а именно мостки, необходимые для того, чтобы строители могли работать на высоте нескольких этажей, называются "леса".
И тут слышится явная ассоциация со словом "лес". Но совершенно непонятно, какая между ними связь? При чем тут лес, как природная зона, и  леса — строительная конструкция?
Или это всего лишь омонимы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сейчас омонимы, а исторически многозначное слово. В недалеком прошлом для размещения рабочих во время строительства устанавливали деревянные конструкции из круглого леса. Это сейчас они из досок или металлические. Так что от термина ЛЕС - строительный материал (собирательное существительное). Из лЕса строили лесА.

Comment: ![Исаакий в лесах](http://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/5802/mister-gonza.d/0_4c0de_68f16a90_XL.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Трубачёв считает, что "леса" произошло от "лес". Фасмер такое предположение лишь допускает, приводя для начала в пример похожие слова из других родственных языков, в которых значения сводятся к "решётка, плетень", то есть составной конструкции определённого типа.
В связи с этим, думаю, уместно вспомнить ещё одно слово: "леса" — нить или шнур (обычно для удочки), которое сегодня употребляется чаще в форме "леска". Можно предположить, что леса — это конструкция, части которой соединяются лесой (тот же плетень, например, плетётся, то есть там есть что-то типа ниток).

Подводя итог, могу сказать, что слово "леса" и форма род. падежа "леса" — это, на мой взгляд, омонимы.

Answer (score 0):

Когда начинается практическая работа, даже для отделки потолка в обычной «малометражке» оказываются необходимы вспомогательные подмостки, леса. В ход идут стремянки, табуреты, столы. Для работы такое «оборудование» достаточно неудобно. Как-то само собой всплывает понимание необходимости и важности того, как сделать строительные леса быстро и надежно.

Comment: Так почему именно "леса"?

Answer (score 0):

Важно, из чего леса возводятся. Но леса (конструктивно и по назначению) представляют из себя систему лестниц и переходов межу ними. По-моему, можно назначить *лестницу* приоритетной. Конечно, прежде без леса было не обойтись, но ведь не назвали же лесами избы, бани, мельницы, мосты.

Answer (score 0):

По-моему все очень просто. Родственность с "лесом" здесь если и есть, то очень дальняя. А вот со словами "лезть", "лестница" — очевидная.